# Bootstrap datepicker not working after build in Durandal 2.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, durandal

After building main-built.js with 'weyland build' my durandal application fails with 'object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker''.
If I run the app with 
`<script src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="app/main">` 
everything is just fine, but if I run from main-built.js the application stops working after navigating to a page with bootstrap datepicker.

Can someone help me on this one?

Comment: i don't know the solution off the top of my head. it sounds like the weyland build minimizer got a little too aggressive and renamed the datepicker function. hope this gives you a little direction?

Comment: where do you add your script reference to bootstrap-datepicker.js? I also use this library in a Durandal 2.0 project with no problems on weyland build.

Comment: i add the reference to bootstrap-datepicker.js in index.html as I do with every other widget or library.

Comment: `$("#dpref").datepicker({language:"pt-BR",format:"mm/yyyy",minViewMode:1,orientation:"top left",autoclose:!0}).on("changeDate",function(e){i(e.date)})`
This is the line that javascript highlights as the point it fails.

Comment: I´ve found the problem. The path to bootstrap-datepicker.js and its locales were not porperly set in weyland.config file. My mistake.